# "Are you wake up?" or "Did you wake up?" Which one is correct?

Tags: questions, auxiliary-verbs

If you want to ask someone if he wake up or not. Which one is correct?

> 1. Are you wake up?
> 2. Did you wake up?

Answer (score 2):

> Did you wake up?

Is correct, the other one is grammatically incorrect.

However, similar questions that begin with "are you" would be:

> Are you **going to** wake up?
>
> Are you **awake**?